# How can I get a variable that holds string that has multiple lines to be only one line?

Tags: python

So I'm writing a program that uses OCR, and when I get an image with a line break and turn that into a string, and print it I get

```
hello there,
how are you?
```

when I want

```
hello there, how are you?
```

How can I do this?

Comment: string.replace("\n" , " ")?

Comment: Doesn't work, the text in the image has a line break.

Comment: `print(repr(string))`, then see what characters you should replace. We can't guess what characters the OCR library you are using is inserting to the outputted string.

Comment: @Improbablyaskingforhelp: it works for the data provided in the question. If the data in the question isn't an accurate representation of your real problem, please update the question.

Comment: it shows up as \n but replacing it doesn't do anything I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @Improbablyaskingforhelp You are probably expecting `replace` to be in-place, which is not. Try `string = string.replace('\n', ' ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the method:

```
imgstring.replace("\n", " ")
```

Alternatively, if you know inbetween which words you want to remove the Newline, you can use regular expressions to find your place where to replace the newline.

A third way of doing this: You can turn the string into a list like so:

```
thisisanexample = "Hello \nSir!"
examplelist = list(thisisanexample)
print(examplelist) #gives ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', '\n', 'S', 'i', 'r', '!']
```

and then iterate through it to find and replace all `'\n'` that you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by replacing backline by a space. If `old_str` is your original string:

```
new_str = old_str.replace("\n"," ")
```

Else you can do:

```
new_str = old_str.split("\n").join(" ")
```

Writing this line in 2 steps will allow you to get a list with only one line in one element.

N.B: if `replace("\n"," ")` does not work, you can try `replace(r"\n", " ")`

Comment: Alright, thank you, I didn't realize I'd have to assign it to a variable again.

Comment: What if I want to only delete one \n? Like if I had this: Hello \n there \n how are you? and I wanted this to be Hello there \n how are you

Comment: What you are asking is purely subjective. What defines the "\n" you want to remove or not? This is the question you should ask yourself and code in function of this.